# Block EU countries to access my site via .htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, block, country

Hi i have basic HTML site with a few pages. I want to block access from EU countries via .htaccess file i have into my root dir. I inserted this code on top of  htaccess file, but seems that not make any changes.

```
<ifModule mod_geoip.c>

GeoIPEnable On
# Add countries you wish to deny here

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE AL DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE AD DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE AM DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE AT DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE AM DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE AZ DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE BY DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE BE DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE BA DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE BG DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE HR DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CY DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CZ DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE DK DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE EE DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE FI DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE FR DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE GE DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE DE DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE GR DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE HU DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE IS DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE IE DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE IT DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE KZ DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE LV DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE LI DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE LT DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE LU DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE MK DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE MT DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE MD DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE MC DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE ME DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE NL DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE NO DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE PL DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE PT DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE RO DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE RU DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE SM DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE RS DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE SK DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE SI DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE ES DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE SE DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CH DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE TR DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE UA DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE GB DenyCountry

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE VA DenyCountry
Allow from all

Deny from env=DenyCountry

</ifModule>
```

Can someone to help me with this? Maybe not works due to mod_geoip.c is not enabled as module into cPanel?

Comment: Just curious if this is about that GDPR thing? :)

Comment: Yes. For GDRP. :)

Comment: It's not advisable to use htaccess for blocking an entire country.  If you have access to WHM just create a custom ModSecurity rule to block the countries you want to exclude.

Comment: So what to do ? Any advice how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making a page on another website letting them know that they have lost access to your site specifically due to GDPR.  Then a visitor from an EU country would be redirected to that page.

You would need to have sudo permissions and be running Apache, because this requires the IP2Location Apache Module in order to run.

You can use this to generate the code: 
https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-redirection#source-codes

Code:

```
    <!-- language: htaccess -->
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^AT$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^BE$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^BG$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^HR$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^CY$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^CZ$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^DK$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^EE$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^FI$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^FR$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^DE$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^GR$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^HU$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^IE$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^IT$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^LV$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^LT$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^LU$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^MT$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^NL$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^PL$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^PT$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^RO$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^SK$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^SI$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^ES$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^SE$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^GB$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/gdpr-page/ [L]
```